# Do certain exception errors occur only in the debugger?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio

In a program I accidentally called `closeHandle()` twice on a mutex handle (closing the handle that was already closed).

When running the code in the debugger, I received the exception error `An invalid HANDLE was specified.` as expected.

However, running the program "normally" as a stand alone (outside of the debugger) the exception does not appear or any other error. Program appears to run normally.

Is this just a setting in Visual Studio .NET 2003 or is there more behind it?

Comment: Perhaps you are running the debug build in VS .NET, but when double-clicking you are running the release build?

Comment: That's documented behavior of closeHandle(). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx: "If the application is running under a debugger, the function will throw an exception if it receives either a handle value that is not valid or a pseudo-handle value."

Comment: I have seen similar behavior with asserts.  Conditional compiling could do it.

Comment: The debug version of the standard library has a very different memory manager than the production version (On MS DevStudio). For example the debug memory manager is designed to be more robust (ie it may not crash on double delete). The cost of robustness is that it is slower (but it will give you warnings when things go wrong). The production version of the memory manager is designed to be fast. So it does not surprise me that different lib components have different behaviors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> If the application is running under a debugger, the function will throw an exception if it receives either a handle value that is not valid or a pseudo-handle value. This can happen if you close a handle twice, or if you call CloseHandle on a handle returned by the FindFirstFile function instead of calling the FindClose function.

Comment: "Throw an exception"?!  I would expect MSDN documentation writers to know better.  C functions do not throw exceptions.  In the context of Win32 exceptions (aka Structured Exception Handling), exceptions get *raised*, not thrown.